# pgAdmin не подключается к серверу

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin4

Пытаюсь создать базу на postgresql, но почему то pgAdmin выдает ошибку на дефолтных установках

[image: Скрин ошибки и конфигурации]
[image: Скрин ошибки с другим портом]

Comment: У Вас сервис postgresql запущен?

Comment: https://learn.coderslang.com/ru/0119-setting-up-and-getting-started-with-postgresql/

Comment: Да, все запущено

Comment: По шагам из урока прошелся, на моменте psql -U postgres ошибка что psql не является командной, хотя я даже в path все добавить пробовал... При этом pgAdmin все еще не работает